# Sub/Superscripts BUT not above each other

Tags: subscripts, superscripts

In latex, if I want to write `$F$` with subscripts and superscripts, as `F_a^b` I get `\[F_a^b\]`. In my case though I want the `b` to be a superscript but slight after `a` -- that is not directly on top of a. How would I do that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please don't use `$$....$$` -- it's deprecated. Use `\[...\]` instead. Are you thinking of covariant, contravariant indices, perhaps?

Comment: Oh maybe if this is what they are called?

Comment: Woops! I edited it, using [\...\], but I do not assume this is what you mean, isn't it?

Comment: `\[ F_{a}^{\,b} \]` perhaps

Comment: Corrected the 'typo' ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A quick and dirty way is to use `\,` for example for the superscript, which inserts a smaller space, `\;` even more and `\quad` will add (too) much space.

As an alternative, the `\indices` - macro from `tensor` - package can be used if the covariant-contravariant way of superscripts/subscripts is needed!

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{tensor}

\begin{document}

Normal: 
\[ F_{a}^{b} \]

Some spacing:

\[ F_{a}^{\,b} \]

Some more spacing:
\[ F_{a}^{\;b} \]

Incredible more spacing:
\[ F_{a}^{\quad b} \]

With tensor - package: \verb!\indices! - command:

\[ F\indices{_a^b}\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Some variants:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
  F_a^b, F_a^{\,b}, F_a^{\>b}, F_a^{\;b}, {F_a}^b
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

this is the style of sub- and superscripts used for tensor notation, which,
i have been led to believe, can go on and on ...

the example here is probably bogus, but the technique is straightforward.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
  F_a{}^b{}_c{}^d
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The other answers already pin-down how to do this in math mode.  In case you or someone else is interested in doing this in text mode, here is how:

```tex
F\textsubscript{a}\textsuperscript{b}
```

The above will typeset "F" horizontally followed by a subscript "a" horizontally followed by a superscript "b".